# Node package to automatically generate api from database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a MySQLdatabase that was built for a PHP project. I want to migrate from PHP to Node and use an Express (or similar) API to interact with the database. Is there any node package that can generate the endpoints automatically?

Comment: LoopBack, SailsJs, etc. These are frameworks, you still have to code the business logic in it

Comment: @JorgeObregon have you used Sails for this? I prefer it to loopback but I havent used either myself

Comment: yes, @Peter Smith. They both work in similar ways, however, LoopBack is more 'robust' in the sense is backed by larger corps, hence a larger ecosystem where you can find support in case you need it.

Answer (score 2):

See LoopBack:

- https://loopback.io/

On the website:

> ### Set up models and create REST APIs in minutes
>
> Easy-to-use CLI wizard Create models based on your schema if you have
>   one Create dynamic models if you don't Built-in API Explorer Model
>   relation support
>
> Define hasMany, belongsTo, hasAndBelongsToMany relationships
>   **Automatically generates corresponding relational REST endpoints**

Of course it will not make all of the work for you but it may help.